# Generic browser update anchor link

Tags: html, browser, cross-browser

I want to show a notification message on my website on browsers that do not support certain html5 features. Have already accomplished that using feature detection with Modernizr.js.

Now in the notification message I wish to add a **upgrade anchor link** clicking on which a user shall be directed to the respective browser update page automatically. Say user is on IE on windows 7 then he/she shall be redirected to the latest IE version of windows 7, say a user is on chrome android 2.3 he/she shall be redirected to the latest chrome version for android 2.3 etc.

As I see one way of doing this is by pointing the **upgrade anchor link** to a third party site url (naturally it has to be a trusted site) which will redirect based on browser and OS. Couldn't find any such service. So is there any such trusted service?

Or is there any other better way of doing this?

Comment: Set links for all major browsers, and depending on the user agent show/hide the appropriate one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UpdateMyBrowser.org](http://updatemybrowser.org) provides a widget that pops up when the browser is old. But you could let modernizr decide when to load it.

Then there are these websites that show the browser's version and provide an update link if it's outdated: [WhatBrowser.org](http://whatbrowser.org) (by Google) and [WhatIsMyBrowser.com](http://www.whatismybrowser.com). [Browser-Update.org](http://browser-update.org) provides an html popup when it detects an old browser, but it doesn't point you to the right update.

One problem I have with all of them is that they send you to the browser's download page. Yet most current browsers update themselves automatically by default, and if they don't, a download page is rarely the easiest way to update the browser. In fact, your examples, Chrome for Android and IE are the exception to that. Maybe it would be more informative to present the user with instructions on how to do the actual update:

- Firefox: [Update from the About window](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/update-firefox-latest-version)
- Chrome: [Update from the About window](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95414)
- Safari: [Update from the Mac App Store](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1338)
- Mobile Safari: [Update iOS](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4623)
- Opera: Help menu > Check for Updates

Comment: @mikemaccana I'm in the process of updating the site, all browser versions are up to date again as of now.

Answer (score 1):

If you access github with an older browser, for example IE8, a yellow bar pops up with a link to their advice page, which takes a similar approach :

https://help.github.com/articles/supported-browsers